# Bypass / Ignore all MouseEvents

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

I have a Jframe that is the size of the entire Monitor. It is intended to temporarily darken the Screen. When i move the mouse onto the screen, the Jframe is animated to get more transparent and at the end it is not visible.

However if i enter the screen before the JFrame is set to visible = false, it captures all mouseclicks.

What i want to achieve is that any mouseEvent on the JFrame will "fall through" the JFrame and triggers whatever lies behind it, as if the JFrame did not exist. (Even if the Windows Explorer lies behind it for example)

Capturing all events and using convertMouseEvent does not help here, because i will never know the target of the MouseEvent.

Comment: Instead of using visible = false, could you use `dispose()`? Just a thought.

Comment: No because when visible = false there is no problem anymore. The problem is when visible is still true.

Comment: A `JFrame` will catch events unless it is ***entirely*** transparent.

Comment: Yes... i noticed that... and then i came here and asked this question....